# How to retrieve multiples arrays from one form post excluding some inputs

Tags: php, forms

I have a form sort like this:

```
<form id="manual" method="post" action="view.php">
<input type="text" name="myfield[]" ....... />
<input type="text" name="myfield[]" ....... />
<input type="text" name="myfield[]" ....... />
<input type="text" name="myfield2[]" ....... />
<input type="text" name="myfield2[]" ....... />
<input type="text" name="myfield2[]" ....... />
<input type="text" name="myfield3[]" ....... />
<input type="text" name="myfield3[]" ....... />
<input type="text" name="myfield3[]" ....... />
<input type="hidden" name="room_id" ....... />
<button type="submit" class="confirm">Send</button>
</form>
```

each additional set of input is created on demand using jquery and the new row of inputs is named myfield+x. Now im stuck on the php side to retrieve the data from the POST, cause i dont see the way to foreach each array name on one loop and exclude the hidden input field "room_id", i tried to use a incremental variable like $i++, but it break the foreach:

```
$items1 = "";
$i = "";

    foreach($_POST['myfield'] as $key1 => $text_field)

{   

    $items1 = implode('||', $_POST['myfield'.$i]);        

}

echo $items1;
```

Im imploding using || to separate each input without worry about the use of special characters. Maybe is a simple issue to solve but too many hours on the pc make me slow, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you want to check if a posted variable (or any variable) is an array use is_array(). http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

Comment: Can you change your input names to arrays -> `name="myfield[]"` to `name="myfield[1][]"`, `name="myfield2[]"` to `myfield[2][]`, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST as $k=>$v){
if(is_array($v)){
$implodes[]=implode("||",$v);
}
}
print_r($implodes);
```

Answer (score -1):

Method 1 : In your First Set You Should Place an Integer Value with this like myfield1[], place a hidden counter in form, so you can use counter in foreach.

You can also you

```
<?php
$items='';
$exclude_field=array('room_id','counter');
foreach($_POST as $key=>value) :
if(!in_array($key,$exclude_field):
$items.=$val . "||";
endif;
endforeach;
trim($items,"||");
?>
```